# How to not assign bind events 

Tags: jquery

I'm doing a bind to document like below,

```
$(document).bind('click',doThis);
```

But i have a text area `#t1` and i dont want the bind event to be assigned to #t1 how can i do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).bind('click',function (e) {

if (e.target.id!='t1') doThis();
});
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah i know  - its just a matter of "used to". the $ can be safely removed.

Comment: Oops, wait, it won't be `this` at all. `this` will be `document` ([proof](http://jsbin.com/aqocux/2)). You want `e.target.id` (which will only work reliably because `textarea` elements can't have child elements), [like this](http://jsbin.com/aqocux/3). In the general case (e.g., if it were a `div`), you'd need to do something like `if (!$(e.target).closest("#t1")[0]) { ... }` (e.g.: was there a `#t1` element anywhere in the path from the clicked element to the document).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : Gushhh    yeah. this wont help. Edited.

Answer (score 3):

The code you've quoted hooks the event on the document, not all elements within it. Events in the DOM bubble from the source element up through all intermediary elements to the document unless that propagation is stopped, which you can do in jQuery using `event.stopPropagation()`. So you could hook the `click` event on your text area and use `event.stopPropagation()` (or `return false`) to prevent the event going up to the document level. E.g.:

```
$("#t1").click(false);
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/aqocux) | [source](http://jsbin.com/aqocux/edit)

There, the `false` tells jQuery that the event handler should just return `false` (it's a shortcut). In a jQuery event handler, `return false;` stops propagation and also prevents any default action the event might have had (in this case, it doesn't have one, but for instance if it were an `a` element, the default action would be to follow the link).

Answer (score 0):

You can use .not() selector

```
$(document).not('#t1').bind('click',doThis);
```

**EDIT**

```
$("*").not('#t1').bind('click',doThis);
```

Comment: No, `not` removes matched elements from the set. But the set returned by `$(document)` only has one element in it: `document`. Calling `not('#t1')` on it has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#t1').unbind();
```

I hope unbinding the id before manipulating it will solve your problem

Comment: No, the event isn't bound to the text area, so calling `unbind` on it will have no effect.

Comment: $(document).bind('click', function() {
             $('#txt1').click(false);
                alert("this is the tessu");


            });

Comment: this works fine whwther you put $('#txt1').click(false) outsid ethe document or inside .I just tried it Tj crowder is just excelent in his explanation below